# extend ubuntu patirtion on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage

I want to install a python package, but it don't work because there is not enough space on Ubuntu patirtion. I have installed Windows10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. I have enough Space on my windows System, but I need to extend my Ubuntu space. I have created a new patirtion with 10GiB, with these 10GiB I want to extend the space on my Ubuntu patirtion.
I tried to solve this with gparted, but I cannot resize/move my Ubuntu patirtion.
Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: You can't repartition from a live running system. You don't create additional partitions to be able to extend your primary Ubuntu partition. Edit your question and show me a `gparted` screenshot, and I'll take a look for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: The process is complex, beginning with telling Windows to shrink the filesystem on its partition, disable Windows "Fast Boot" option (be sure you can boot Windows after these steps), boot from a Live USB distribution (there are specialized `gparted` distributions,  but almost any Linux Live USB will do), run `gparted`, shrink the Windows partition (don't overshrink, remember what you told the Windows filesystem), embiggen your adjacent Linux filesystem, then reboot.

Comment: @waltinator You don't want to use `gparted` to resize the Windows NTFS partitions, you want to use the Windows Disk Management tool. Use `gparted` for the ext4 partitions.